# How to get information from all my channels on a certain account with LiveBroadcasts: list?

Tags: python-requests, youtube-api

I'm trying to get all the broadcasts from both my channels. I'm using 
LiveBroadcasts: list for it.

I think I can obtain it by using onBehalfOfContentOwner with my own ContentID, but I haven't one.

```
def get_broadcasts_with_certain_statuses(api_key, access_token, statuses):
    """Returns all broadcasts on your channel with certain statuses.

    Statuses can be: ready, testing etc."""

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    }

    params = (
        ('part', 'snippet,contentDetails,status'),
        ('broadcastType', 'all'),
        ('maxResults', '50'),
        ('mine', 'true'),
        ('key', api_key),
    )

    r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts', headers=headers, params=params)

    streams_data = {}
    if r.ok:
        for i, item in enumerate(r.json()['items']):
            if item['status']['lifeCycleStatus'] in statuses:
                     streams_data[i] = {'title': item['snippet']['title'], 'id': item['id']}
    else:
        return None
    return streams_data
```

I expected this code will return information from both my channels, but it only returned from one of them. So I cant't understand how to explain that I need information from both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it yet, but I understood that once I got a refresh token, I need to choose the channel I'm finding information about. So I just created another app and another refresh token.